# How to add sequential numbers say 1,2,3 etc. to each file name and also for each line of the file content in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ksh, sequential-number

I want to add sequential number for each file and its contents in a directory. The sequential number should be prefixed with the filename and for each line of its contents should have the same number prefixed. In this manner, the sequential numbers should be generated for all the files(for names and its contents) in the sub-folders of the directory.

I have tried using maxdepth, rename, print function as a part. but it throws error saying that "-maxdepth" - not a valid option.

I have already a part of code(to print the names and contents of text files in a directory) and this logic should be appended with it.

```
#!bin/bash
cd home/TESTING
for file in home/TESTING;
do
find home/TESTING/ -type f -name *.txt -exec basename {} ';' -exec cat {} \;
done
```

P.s - print, rename, maxdepth are not working

If the name of the first file is File1.txt and its contents is mentioned as "Louis" then the output for the filename should be 1File1.txt and the content should be as "1Louis".The same should be replaced with 2 for second file. In this manner, it has to traverse through all the subfolders in the directory and print accordingly. I have already a part of code and this logic should be appended with it.

Answer (score 2):

There should be fail safe if you execute cd in a script. You can execute command in wrong directory if you don't.

In your attempt, the output would be the same even without the for cycle, as `for file in home/TESTING` only pass `home/TESTING` as argument to `for` so it only run once. In case of 
`for file in home/TESTING/*` this would happen else how.

I used find without `--maxdepth`, so it will look into all subdirectory as well for `*.txt` files. If you want only the current directory `$(find /home/TESTING/* -type f -name "*.txt")` could be replaced to `$(ls *.txt)` as long you do not have directory that end to `.txt` there will be no problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

# try cd to directory, do things upon success.
if cd /home/TESTING ;then
      # set sequence number
      let "x = 1"

      # pass every file to for that find matching, sub directories will be also as there is no maxdeapth.
      for file in $(find /home/TESTING/* -type f -name "*.txt") ; do

            # print sequence number, and base file name, processed by variable substitution. 
            # basename can be used as well but this is bash built in.
            echo "${x}${file##*/}"

            # print file content, and put sequence number before each line with stream editor.
            sed 's#^#'"${x}"'#g' ${file}

            # increase sequence number with one.
            let "x++"
      done

      # unset sequence number
      unset 'x'
else
      # print error on stderr
      echo 'cd to /home/TESTING directory is failed' >&2
fi
```

Variable Substitution:

There is more i only picked this 4 for now as they similar.

`${var#pattern}` - Use value of var after removing text that match pattern from the left

`${var##pattern}` - Same as above but remove the longest matching piece instead the shortest

`${var%pattern}` - Use value of var after removing text that match pattern from the right

`${var%%pattern}` - Same as above but remove the longest matching piece instead the shortest

So `${file##*/}` will take the variable of $file and drop every caracter `*` before the last `##` slash `/`. The `$file` variable value not get modified by this, so it still contain the path and filename.

`sed 's#^#'"${x}"'#g' ${file}` sed is a stream editor, there is whole books about its usage, for this particular one. It usually placed into single quote, so `'s#^#1#g'` will add 1 the beginning of every line in a file.`s` is substitution, `^` is the beginning of the file, `1` is a text, `g` is global if you not put there the g only first mach will be affected.
`#` is separator it can be else as well, like `/` for example. I brake single quote to let variable be used and reopened the single quote.

If you like to replace a text, .txt to .php, you can use `sed 's#\.txt#\.php#g' file` , `.` have special meaning, it can replace any singe character, so it need to be escaped `\`, to use it as a text. else not only `file.txt` will be matched but `file1txt` as well.

It can be piped , you not need to specify file name in that case, else you have to provide at least one filename in our case it was the `${file}` variable that contain the filename. As i mentioned variable substitution is not modify variable value so its still contain the filename with path.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I have changed x++ into x=x+1 since i faced some issue with that. Could you please explain to me these commands (echo "${x}${file##*/}"   , sed 's#^#'"${x}"'#g' ${file}) in detail if possible. I am trying to understand it. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I updated the answer, let me know is something unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Great explanation! :)

Comment: I made a mistake in sed example.  `.` can replace any character and need to be escaped in this case.

Comment: yeah thanks. I have to modify the code according to the new requirement. I will be asking it as a separate question in stack overflow and will be presenting the code that i have made for it. I am facing some issues with it. If you are getting notified about it pls do answer if you find time. It is just a request.The way you explain things is easy to understand and is crystal clear. Thank you so much for guiding me through this

Comment: Here's the link if you wish to answer-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606127/how-to-separate-the-filenames-and-contents-matching-a-particular-pattern-in-vari