# How to separate the filenames and contents matching a particular pattern in various separate files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I am trying to segregate filenames matching a particular into a separate file and its contents into different files matching particular patterns.I have the filenames with special characters included like '|'

I tried using grep command. Grep Ril and Grep -H to print the filenames,but it is not working.

```
#!bin/bash
cd home/test
let "x = 1"
for file in $(find home/test/* -type f -name "*.txt") ; 
do
var=$(echo "${x}|fill|${file##*/}")
echo "${var}" | grep -n "*|fill|*.txt" >header.txt
myvar=$(sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g' ${file})
echo "${myvar}" |grep -n "*|Ball|*" >Ball.txt
echo "${myvar}" |grep -n "*|Fire|*" >Fire.txt
let x=x+1
done
unset 'x'
let x=x+1
done
unset 'x
```

I have the filenames in this format:

```
1|fill|abc.txt
2|fill|def.txt
```

The 'fill' remains the same in all files. The final file for this should have values like this

```
1|fill|abc.txt
2|fill|def.txt
3...
4...
5...
etc...
```

Then, each file contains different contents.

File1 contains data similar to this pattern:

```
1|Ball|202029|
1|Cat|202029|
1|fire|202898
...
```

File 2 contains data similar to this pattern:

```
2|Bat|202029|
2|Ball|202029|
2|cat|202898
```

Now the final output should be in such a way that all the data containing 'ball' should be in a separate file, 'cat' in separate file, 'fire' in separate file and so on.

Comment: Please provide example for the input file contents from /home/test/. People can understand more easy that way, what you like to do.

Comment: its just a path where i have to execute my script. In that path there is a directory and it contains many folders and sub folders. In that subfolders we have this file1 and file2 etc.., the file 1 and file2 contents are mentioned already..pls tell me whether this information would suffice

Comment: here i should have 4 files totally. One file that displays all the filenames. The next one displaying all the file contents that has 'ball' in it .Another one with 'cat' in it and the fourth one with 'fire' in it.please tell me whether am clear or not. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: grep is not working because you did not specified 3th argument what is one or more  file name normally. `grep pattern filename` or you can feed it by pipe with text  `echo 'text' | grep pattern`

Comment: I have assigned the echo command to a variable eval. and i have used it with the | grep -Ril '*|Fill|* and then the pattern. Then i have given header.txt for my output file

Comment: ah sorry I talked about the greps after that. eval is a command that run text as command in sort. you did not assign the value to eval variable. eval should not be used except you rely need it, its a very powerful command and codes can be exploited if it used wrongly. If you want to assign a command outputs into variable you should go with `var=$(ls | grep "pattern")`

Comment: I have to assign that echo command 'echo "${x}|fill|${file##*/}"' to a variable. can i assign it like this? var = echo "${x}|fill|${file##*/}"' and then trying to print that in header.txt. can you pls tell me whether the approach am following for my requirement is right or not? that is using grep command and printing it in a file

Comment: `var=$(echo "${x}|fill|${file##*/}")` no space alowed in variable assigment `var=$(...)`
so later `myvar = 'sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g' ${file}'` also wrong, `myvar=$(sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g' ${file})`, command should be inside bracers that start with a dollar `variable=$(command)`, in case of myvar you put it into single bracer so you would store the command as text in the variable and not its output.

Comment: am not getting it right :( the required output is not getting printed. Pls tell me if my approach is right for my requirement?is there any other better options..It isn't working. Am new to this unix environment. Am trying to learn

Comment: I tried using this command - echo "${var}" | grep -n "*|F|*.txt" >header.txt. But the value is not getting printed in the header.txt file

Comment: You can edit your question, if you like to present your current progress, and provide adiction information to the people, it is better readbale that way.

Comment: thanks. I have done the update. Can you pls let me know what's wrong in it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure the below code will do the thing you want, but it will be close to it I beleve, let me know and I update is accordingly.

the files below will be in the same directory as the other files you use in the script and as they end .txt as well next script run will read them as well.

```
header.txt
B.txt
C.txt
F.txt
```

```
#!/bin/bash


# i put the directory in variable, so it can be changed at a single place.
dir='/home/test'

#if cd failed , print erron on standard error output and terminate script.
if ! cd "${dir}" ;then
        echo "cd failed into ${dir}" >&2
        exit 1
fi

# set counter to 1
let "x = 1"

# Null file contents or create new file
# without this file content will be preserved from earlier script runs.
> header.txt
> B.txt
> C.txt
> F.txt

# go trhought every file in ${dir} path that name end with .txt and it is a regular file
for file in $(find ${dir} -type f -name "*.txt") ;
do
        # store basefilename in variable with aditional counter number and text |Fill| front of it.
        filename=$(echo "${x}|fill|${file##*/}")
        echo "${filename}" >> header.txt
        # this can be used as well:
        ##echo "${x}|fill|${file##*/}" >> header.txt
        # only difference is you stored the output into variable.

        # find matching line in files
        grep -i '|Ball|' ${file} | sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g' >> B.txt
        grep -i '|Cat|'  ${file} | sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g' >> C.txt
        grep -i '|Fire|' ${file} | sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g' >> F.txt

        # add 1 to counter
        let "x=x+1"
done

# unset counter
unset 'x'
```

Input files:

File1.txt

```
1|Ball|202029|
1|Cat|202029|
1|fire|202898
```

File2.txt

```
2|Bat|202029|
2|Ball|202029|
2|cat|202898
```

Output files:

header.txt

```
1|fill|header.txt
2|fill|B.txt
3|fill|C.txt
4|fill|F.txt
5|fill|File1.txt
6|fill|File2.txt
```

B.txt

```
5|1|Ball|202029|
6|2|Ball|202029|
```

C.txt

```
5|1|Cat|202029|
6|2|cat|202898
```

F.txt

```
5|1|fire|202898
```

Comment: A big thank you for your help!! The header.txt is getting generated as expected. But I couldn't see anything getting printed in the B.txt , C.txt and F.txt files. And am working on it. Thank you so so so much Edvin! :) –

Comment: your question get edited earlier to be better readable, I used the informations there.

Comment: ah i just changed the dir variable in my script so it now match yours `dir='/home/test'`

Comment: yes Edvin. But the contents there is right. No changes in the text, only the format was changed. When i use this command  "grep -i '|Ball|' ${file} | sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g' >> B.txt", B.txt is empty with  no data. The same with C.txt and F.txt

Comment: I saw that too and i edited the dir variable and gave my home path already. But, even then am facing this issue. Can you pls help me with this

Comment: I dont know what is the issue, do you use `grep -i '|Ball|'` ? and not `grep -i '*|Ball|*'` right?

Comment: yes i exactly use the same grep -i  '|Ball|'. not the other one. But y the other one is wrong? and one more thing when i changed the command as grep -i '|Ball|'  | sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g'  ${file}>> B.txt, I got some values in it. But it's wrong. i found that the grep wasn't working properly.

Comment: `grep -i '|Ball|' ${file} | sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g' >> B.txt` is not equal to `grep -i '|Ball|' | sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g' ${file}>> B.txt` sed is read the output of grep so its not need a file as input but grep have nothing to work with as you not give it a file.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I understood. the grep -i '|Ball|' ${file} | sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g' >> B.txt should work perfectly fine?But, i don't know why B.txt is empty. P.S - I also checked the input files and it contains |Ball| for sure.

Comment: try reproducate it step by step, execute `grep -i '|Ball|' /path/file` in a shell itself.
remove | from pattern to se it match to only Ball or not

Comment: yes i am debugging it step by step. It is not giving the required output for this grep -i '|Ball|' /path/file. i replaced /path/file with my path. It is not giving any output.

Comment: you should try every invidual file, that was just an example of mine how to. So I mean `grep -i '|Ball|' /home/test/abc.txt` and so on, if you use `set -x` in the next line after `!#/bin/bash` that switch the script into kind if debuging mode. It will print some info but it not print things like a text get routed into a file.

Comment: yes Edvin. Am working on each and every individual file as you have mentioned. I didn't try only that. let me check the set -x and get back to you. Thank you so much

Comment: I found what was wrong with it. In this line, grep -i '|Ball|' ${file} | sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g' the pipe before Ball should not come. It should be grep -i 'Ball|' ${file} | sed 's/^/'${x}'|/g' because we are appending | in sed command after that. That's y..It's working fine now. Thank you so so much Edvin. U are really great. I actually understood the flow now. Great mentor! Thank you so much :)